# Reading list element jsoup

Tags: html, list, parsing, jsoup

```
<ul class="facilities">
   <li>
      <img src="..." alt="..." title="Bar">
   </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

How can i red the text inside the 'title' attribute in a list. (with jsoup)?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the img element, you can read any attribute of the element as follows:

```
Element img = document.select("img").first();
String title = img.attr("title");
```

To get the titles of all the images in the list, you can iterate over them:

```
Element ul = document.select("ul").first();
Elements imgs = ul.select("img");
for (Element img : imgs) {
    img.attr("title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks faeorx, but the list contains multiple images.  However i figured it out as follows:

```
Elements ele5 = doc.select("div.panel");
Elements subEle5 = ele5.select("img");
for (Element img : subEle5) {
    String venueFacilities = img.attr("Title");
    System.out.println("venueFacilities "+venueFacilities);
}
```

div.panel is the div which contains the 'facilities' list